# how to insert id="getdobval" into input value?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I want to insert a value into `<input type="text" id="getdobtval">` when I am selecting a range value.

For showing output in browser am using `<span id="getdobtval"></span>` instead of this `span` I want insert into text. How can I solve this using javascript?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slider-bottom').slider().on('slide', function(ev) {
    var finalvalue = '';
    var finalbtvalue = '';
    var finalbtprice = '';
    var finalbitvalue = '';
    finalbtprice = 250;
    var newVal = $('#slider-bottom').data('slider').getValue();
    var textval = parseInt(newVal);

    if (textval >= 600 && textval < 6000) {
      finalvalue = 0.075;
      finalbitvalue = textval * finalvalue;
    } else if (textval >= 6000 && textval < 30000) {
      finalvalue = 0.070;
      finalbitvalue = textval * finalvalue;
    } else if (textval >= 30000) {
      finalvalue = 0.065;
      finalbitvalue = textval * finalvalue;
    }
    finalbtvalue = finalbitvalue / finalbtprice;
    if (finalbtvalue) {
      $("#getdobtval").html("<strong>" + finalbtvalue.toFixed(8) + "</strong>");
    }
  });

  $('#slider-bottom').sliderTextInput();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input id="slider-bottom" type="text" name="hrate" data-slider-min="600" data-slider-max="100000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="600" data-slider-tooltip="show" />
  <span id="getdobtval"></span>
  <input type="text" id="getdobtval" name="getdobtval">
  <input type="submit" name="buynow">
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is because you've got two elements with the same `id`. That is invalid. You'll also need to use `val()`, not `html()`, to set the value of an `input` element.

Comment: actually am getting output into <span id="getdobtval"></span> without <input type="text">, just i want remove that <span> replace with <input> , i tried with <input> but not sowing output

Comment: Ok, so what is stopping you from removing the `span`?

Comment: i want insert value into database using span not working, show am thinking to use input, after my work easy , but its not coming

Comment: i'l try with val()

Comment: Thank you its working, i used val(), in javascript now output showing in text box

Answer (score 2):

Create a hidden input box with different id like `dobtval`

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input id="slider-bottom" type="text" name="hrate" data-slider-min="600" data-slider-max="100000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="600" data-slider-tooltip="show" />
  <span id="getdobtval"></span>
  <input type="hidden" id="dobtval" name="dobtval"/>
  <input type="submit" name="buynow">
</form>
```

And in JS use,

```
....
if (finalbtvalue) {
  $('#dobtval').val(finalbtvalue.toFixed(8));// set value in input
  $("#getdobtval").html("<strong>" + finalbtvalue.toFixed(8) + "</strong>");
}
....
```

`id` must be unique, but if you want same HTML then differentiate your elements by their tag name like,

```
$('span#getdobtval').html('....'); // use html() span/div
$('input#getdobtval').val('....'); // use val() for input/textarea
```